How does the PWM protocol work in AC chargers for electric cars?
I'm trying to design an AC charger for electric vehicles. They don't seem to be a big deal in terms of electronic design, but I can't understand how the CP and PP signals work in these devices. So far, I've managed to understand that the CP signal must be read with an analog input of a MCU/MPU, and that indicates how much current should be supplied. However, I can't understand how they work, what algorithm is used to perform a correct charge using the CP and PP signals. Could someone please explain this to me?

You talk about a charger but then you talk about just how a charging station communicates with the charger that is in the EV. Also the signals are well documented on the standard and many websites quoting the standard. Do you have a specific question about how they work?
